# Laravel 7.x Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a 'edit' page for a 'bookshop'. Everything in the front-end seems perfect, but when I click edit after inputting data I get this error: "Creating default object from empty value"

I've tried adding a 'new' as I seen on other topics but it didnt help.

**My controller:**

```
function Update(Request $request){

    $entry = Book::find($request->route('id'));
    $entry->name = $request -> book_name;
    $entry->writer_name = $request->writer_name;
    $entry->isbn = $request->book_isbn;
    $entry->save();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

**It gives error on this line**

```
$entry->name = $request -> book_name;
```

**My router for update**

```
Route::post('/edit/update/{id}','EditController@Update');
```

**My form**

```
<form  method="POST" action="/edit/update/{id}">
```

It is just a basic form that updates the database items. When I click 'edit' (button) after changing some values it gives me the 'Creating default object from empty value' error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$request -> book_name;
```

should be

```
$request->book_name;
```

(without spaces)

I would also recommend using

```
$entry = Book::findOrFail($id);
```

in case the id is not found.  Also, I guess what you mean is:

```
function update(Request $request, $id){
    $entry = Book::findOrFail($id); 
}
```

Comment: Now I get another error... The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.:( I'm literally tired of errors

Comment: be sure to add the {{ csrf_field() }} inside your <form>, if not you will get a CSRF error.